# docker file tomcat configuration with docker file

Tags: docker, tomcat9, sqldatasource

i want to create a docker file with tomcat server .
i have two war files war 1 and war 2.
i copied war1.xml into /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/
i copied war2.xml into /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/

here is the context of war1.xml

```
<Resources>
    <Resource
            name="jdbc/app1"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            auth="Container"
            username="root"
            password="toto"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306">
    </Resource>
    <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" base="/app/ml/ts/config/"
                  webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes"/>

    <ResourceLink global="app1" name="app1" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Resources>
```

here are my docker files :

```
FROM tomcat:8.0-jre8-alpine

COPY app1/target/war1.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY app2/target/app2.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/


COPY app1/src/main/resources/conf/app1.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/
COPY app2/src/main/resources/app2/conf/app2.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/

COPY app1/src/main/resources/app1/scripts/* 

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

here is mysql docker file :

```
    FROM mysql:5.7
    
    # Add a database
    ENV MYSQL_DATABASE MyDb
    
    ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD toto
    
    # Add the content of the sql-scripts/ directory to your image
    # All scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ are automatically
    # executed during container startup
    COPY app-livraison/src/main/resources/db/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

here is my docker compose file :

    version: '3'
services:
  tomcat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.tomcat
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  mysql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toto
      MYSQL_DATABASE: Mydb
```

but the context could not add the datasource , i have the following error :

```
BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name '"glc-batch"'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [app1] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [app1].
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
... 48 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name '"app1"'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [app1] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [app1].

Comment: How do you instanciate the container ? Any docker-compose file ? mysql://localhost:3306 is set up but there is no way java will find any databases there, need more context.

Comment: @Ludwig i have a docker file for my sql database which corresponds to the url and port , i think that the problem is that the datasource is not bound to the context via context.xml

Comment: You won't access any other container from the java container with localhost.
Both container (java and sql) need to be on the same docker network, and accessed by their net aliases, I would advise setting up a docker compose file, or show the exact command you launched the container with, can't be of any help without that.

Comment: @Ludwig i complete my question with docker files and docker compose

Comment: From the war1 file, you can access to the database with url="jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306" which will point to the mysql container, I guess you will also need to modify this file according to MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

Comment: @Ludwig stil the same problem of data source even if i added this line to tomcat docker file : COPY /docker/mysql/mysql-connector.jar /usr/local/tomcat/lib/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251645/discussion-between-ares-and-ludwig).

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the JNDI-NAME , in the properties file you should give the complete name defined in server.xml : jndi/datasourceName without quotation marks.
that was not a docker problem.
thanks